# Upper bound for the complex Beta function

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, special-functions, gamma-function, beta-function

Is there any work or reference regarding upper bounds for the complex beta function defined by

\begin{equation}
B(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x) \Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)},
\end{equation} 
for $\Re{x} >0$ and $\Re{y}>0$.

Comment: I already went through that reference, but they only provide bounds for real beta function!

Comment: Sorry ! I did misread the problem. Cheers.

Comment: I would look into applying Stirling since it offers good lower and upper bounds for $\Gamma$

Answer (score 0):

The command of Mathematica

```
NMaximize[{ComplexExpand[Abs[Gamma[s + I*t]*Gamma[a + I*b]/Gamma[s + a + I*(t + b)]]],s > 0 &&a > 0},{s, t, a, b}]
```

outputs "NMaximize::cvdiv: Failed to converge to a solution. The function may be unbounded." and

> `{4.7857*10^8, {s -> 0.32798, t -> 0.720557, a -> 0.,  b -> -2.08956*10^-9}}`

The command of Mathematica

```
s = 1; t = a; MaxLimit[ ComplexExpand[Abs[Gamma[s + I*t]*Gamma[a + I*b]/Gamma[s + a + I*(t + b)]]], {t,b} -> {0, 0},Direction -> "FromAbove"]
```

results in $\infty$, confiming it.